# I got an error swift on xcode7.2

Tags: swift, xcode7

The error tells me "downcast from ‘[NSindexPath]’ only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use ‘!’?" I don't know how to fix this. need your help.

```
  func deselectAllRows(tableView:UITableView) {

    tableView.reloadData()
      // below is the code I got an error for
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows as? [NSIndexPath] {
        for indexPath in selectedRows {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, you can see the function signature:

```
func indexPathsForSelectedItems() -> [NSIndexPath]?
```

Which means you already have `[NSIndexPath]` so you don't need to cast it. Just unwrap the optional, like this:

```
if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
    for indexPath in selectedRows {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    }
}
```